# Bomblab - Phase 4

Tags: assembly

I'm working on this assembly project for school called bomblab. The project is to defuse several binary "bombs" by using the correct input. 
The project has 6 phases and I'm currently on phase 4.
Using gdb I have disassembled the code for this function and I have come to 4 conclusions.

1. The input must be 2 integers. (I examined $0x4028c5 and found %d %d)
2. The first integer is 6.
3. The function uses the 2nd integer as input and the output must be 8 to defuse the bomb.
4. The function is recursive

Here is the disassembled code with comments that might not be accurate (but i hope they are)

```
phase_4
0x0000000000401020 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x0000000000401024 <+4>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401029 <+9>:     lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
0x000000000040102e <+14>:    mov    $0x4028c5,%esi
0x0000000000401033 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000401038 <+24>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x000000000040103d <+29>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x0000000000401040 <+32>:    jne    0x401049 <phase_4+41>
0x0000000000401042 <+34>:    cmpl   $0xe,0xc(%rsp)
0x0000000000401047 <+39>:    jbe    0x40104e <phase_4+46>
0x0000000000401049 <+41>:    callq  0x401574 <explode_bomb>
0x000000000040104e <+46>:    mov    $0xe,%edx
0x0000000000401053 <+51>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
0x0000000000401058 <+56>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi
0x000000000040105c <+60>:    callq  0x400fe2 <func4>
0x0000000000401061 <+65>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
0x0000000000401064 <+68>:    jne    0x40106d <phase_4+77>
0x0000000000401066 <+70>:    cmpl   $0x6,0x8(%rsp)
0x000000000040106b <+75>:    je     0x401072 <phase_4+82>
0x000000000040106d <+77>:    callq  0x401574 <explode_bomb>
0x0000000000401072 <+82>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
0x0000000000401076 <+86>:    retq

Dump of assembler code for function func4:

0x0000000000400fe2 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp //subtracks 8 from rsp
0x0000000000400fe6 <+4>:     mov    %edx,%eax  
0x0000000000400fe8 <+6>:     sub    %esi,%eax   
0x0000000000400fea <+8>:     mov    %eax,%ecx   //rcx = rax
0x0000000000400fec <+10>:    shr    $0x1f,%ecx  // shifts rcx to the right by 0x1f
0x0000000000400fef <+13>:    add    %ecx,%eax   // ads rcx to rax
0x0000000000400ff1 <+15>:    sar    %eax            //arithmetic shift to the right
0x0000000000400ff3 <+17>:    lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ecx //??
0x0000000000400ff6 <+20>:    cmp    %edi,%ecx   // compares %edi & $ecx
0x0000000000400ff8 <+22>:    jle    0x401006 <func4+36> // jump if ecx < edi
0x0000000000400ffa <+24>:    lea    -0x1(%rcx),%edx     //edx = edx - rcx - 1
0x0000000000400ffd <+27>:    callq  0x400fe2 <func4>    // calls itself
0x0000000000401002 <+32>:    add    %eax,%eax   //eax*2
0x0000000000401004 <+34>:    jmp    0x40101b <func4+57> 
0x0000000000401006 <+36>:    mov    $0x0,%eax 
0x000000000040100b <+41>:    cmp    %edi,%ecx
0x000000000040100d <+43>:    jge    0x40101b <func4+57>
0x000000000040100f <+45>:    lea    0x1(%rcx),%esi
0x0000000000401012 <+48>:    callq  0x400fe2 <func4>
0x0000000000401017 <+53>:    lea    0x1(%rax,%rax,1),%eax
0x000000000040101b <+57>:    add    $0x8,%rsp // adds 8 to rsp
0x000000000040101f <+61>:    retq
```

So I guess my question is what does function 4 actually do? 
Or better yet what must my input be in order to get that desired 8.
I'm sorry if this question is not formatted correctly and for my subpar english.
I've spent hours staring at this code so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The comments are not accurate. Can't you actually step over the code in debugger to see what those instructions does? Some mistakes and confusing things would probably clear up much better, if you would actually see what is truly happening. If you don't have it in runnable form, maybe just clean that disasm a bit to make it compilable into small testing app, so you can experiment (although it may be tricky for beginner to fully understand how to clean that up into compilable small app while preserving everything).

Comment: I've been experementing with it for hours. No matter what I put in there it always returns 6. I´ve tried small numbers, really big numbers and negative numbers, nothing changes. If I step any further in the code or run it I detonate the binary bomb which lowers my grade and sends me back to square one.
I also have no idea how to make it into a testing app.
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: From the `cmp    $0x6,%eax` I would say the expected result is `6`, not `8`. BTW, can you step into the function, so you can watch how it works? In `gdb` you certainly can. If you just call over it, you will hardly figure anything interesting.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I did step into the function, that's what the bottom half of the code posted is. Everything after "Dump of assembler code for function func4:" is the code for the function I need to figure out.

Regarding  cmp $0x6,%eax , I believe thats comparing the first integer of my input, which is 6, like you said. What I have yet to figure out is the second one.

Comment: no, it's comparing the `eax`, which contains result of `call func4`. The next `cmpl   $0x6,0x8(%rsp)` compares against one of the inputs to be also value `6`. If you did step into it, you should probably fix your comments, like `lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ecx //??` or `lea    -0x1(%rcx),%edx     //edx = edx - rcx - 1`  ... (hint: in Intel syntax those would be `lea ecx,[rax+rsi]` and `lea edx,[rcx-1]`).

Comment: Also probably try to grasp the meaning of those calculations, for example `shr    $0x1f,%ecx` technically does shift `ecx` `0x1f` times right, but what does that mean? `0x1f` is `31` and `ecx` is 32 bit register, so shifting it 31 times right will leave you with the 32th bit in first bit position, i.e. extract the sign bit as 0/1 value. Which is sort of weird, as I don't even see how you would get to negative values there, but I didn't really run it in my head into some deep recursion, just checked your assumptions a bit and figured out you can straight away work on fixing them first.

Comment: So to summarize: as far as I can tell, you are hunting wrong assumptions. The result of `func4` should be 6 and one of the input values should be 6 too. Also the other input value must be 0..14 (`cmpl   $0xe,0xc(%rsp)` `jbe    ... //skip explode`) ... So there are only 15 possible input values for `func4`.  (I'm intentionally not addressing input values as first/second, as I'm not sure which is which, because I don't recall from head 64b calling convention for `sscanf`, but you should see in debugger which input ended where in stack memory).

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, you're a real lifesaver. The correct input was 6 6

Comment: Yay, *I* defused the bomb... would rather see *you* checking few more times x86 instruction reference guide and learning better how they work. :) feel free to ask if you still don't get why something was like it was, for example I have no idea where you got `8`...